# Chinese expression for "go out early and return early"

Tags: expressions, verbs, chengyu

I'm Looking for a Chinese expression that means something like "go out early and return early" or "the sooner you leave, the sooner you can come back". It expresses a wish for a person who is leaving the house (e.g. for work) to return in a timely manner.

I thought it was 早去早回來, but I can't find a reference for this. The only similar phrase I could find was 早出晚歸, which has a very different meaning.

Comment: see 早去早回 in bkrs

Comment: Not suitable but 早死早超生 is nice for comedic relief.

Comment: Similar is 快去快回

Answer (score 3, accepted):

早去早回 means exactly what you want as "go out early and return early" or "the sooner you leave, the sooner you can come back".
早出晚归 means "go out early and return late" which is always used to describe a person work hard and busy.

Answer (score 0):

有一句成语非常适合这种场景“归心似箭”。它的意思是，想要回家的愿望如同射出的箭一样强烈。

Answer (score -2):

`早死早超生`负面情绪多一点，`早死早投胎`更多正能量的表达。